# Android Menu Icon with Title : Title doesn't display

Tags: android

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@+id/refresh" android:title="Home"
  android:icon="@drawable/menu_home" />
 <item android:id="@+id/search" android:title="Search"
  android:icon="@drawable/menu_search" />
 <item android:id="@+id/help" android:title="Help" android:icon="@drawable/menu_help" />
</menu>
```

Icon is getting displayed but title doesn't. Please advise.

Comment: Odd, what size, in pixels, are your icons? I wonder if they are too big and pushing the text off of the menu.

Comment: looks like i need 48 * 48 . Let me try that.

Comment: That was it. @Andrew thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks for having this problem, because it just happened to me, and resizing fixed it. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer then...

The size of menu pixes can be too large (such as 72x72). Make sure you use the proper size icons for your current display.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but my menu icon size was 32x32. And still displayed over the text. So, I played a little with the sizes, and set it to about 47x47 and it finally worked.

So, if this happens, try to play with the image sizes.