# Actionmenu: Show Title AND Icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title, xml-drawable

I use this code in my menu.xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/physics"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_***"
        android:title="@string/physics"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Now my Icons aren't very much saying about the button they stand for.
So I wan't display them AND the title.
After long google research I found this on @stackoverflow:
[Android Menu Icon with Title : Title doesn't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394647/android-menu-icon-with-title-title-doesnt-display)
But it's about the icons. I downloaded my icons already in the right size and put them in the right folder.

And I don't have problems with my icons, they are showing great, but when you see a line chart, you don't automatically think of physics, do you?

Any idea, how to display both? I also added a sting, it doesn't show up (is it even possible?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any idea, how to display both?

Replace:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

with:

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

Comment: @Lesik2008: `withText` is a hint and may not be honored in all screen sizes and orientations. Try rotating your screen to landscape, or running on a tablet, to see your label.

Comment: Okay, they are showing on a Tablet screen, but both strings aren't long! It looks like I have a bunch of space between the icons, why isn't it showing? :(

Comment: @Lesik2008: I have no way to know, sorry.